# Is there a way to connect the Blueimp Gallery with File Upload?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, blueimp

I'm using the Blueimp gallery on my website and I love it! Especially because of the Bootstrap Image Gallery extension.

My problem is, that it's always lot of work to open my pictures with Photoshop and create thumbnails.. So I was looking for a way to upload my pictures to my server and perhaps create thumbnails automatically.

So I found that Blueimp also have a File Uploader. It's without thumbnail function. But I also found jQuery NailThumb, which creates Thumbnail. It's not for resizing, but it would be okay for me.

Now my question:

Is it possible to connect the Blueimp Gallery with the Blueimp File Uploader? I want to upload the pictures with the File Uploader and the Gallery should automatically add them to the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Hey, sorry, my english is not the best, but i try my best to give you so much information you need :D

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Blanchard

My current project is on my local server, so i can't share any links, but i will try to explain.. I added the Blueimp gallery with "Bootstrap Image Gallery" extension [Image Gallery](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) it's working great, i can add pictures via :

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>
```

And i also have the Blueimp File Uploader [File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

It's great to upload my pictures to the page. But when i use the Uploader, the pictures are not automatically in my Bootstrap Image Gallery, cause there is no connection between those both scripts. Is there a chance to connect them? So that my gallery automatically sees when i upload an image with the uploader?